# Combine after() and slideDown()

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown, jquery-after

I am adding an element on a certain condition. But I don't want it suddenly appear but rather would like to slide it down. Here's how I add it:

```
$('.myDiv').after('<div>added content</div>');
```

How do I combine it with slideDown?

Comment: Please expand your example code. Show us your HTML and the JS event you're using.

Comment: `$('.myDiv').hide().after('<div>added content</div>').slideDown();`

Comment: @Archer: Almost.  `.after` returns the `.myDiv`, not the new element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
$(".myDiv").after("<div style='display:none;'>added content</div>"); 
$(".myDiv").next("div").slideDown();
```

Good Luck !!

Comment: Not quite.  `.after` literally puts the new element after the element, next to it.  It does not add it as a child, that's what `.append` does.

Answer (score 3):

Try this out:

```
$('.myDiv').after('<div style="display:none">added content</div>').next().slideDown();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.next()` on the div to which it is attached because `.after()`... adds the element as a sibling to the div to which it is added

Try this

```
$('.myDiv').after('<div style="display:none;" class="newDiv">New Content</div>'); 

$('.myDiv').next('.newDiv').slideDown();
```

Answer (score -1):

first make sure the new content that you input is hidden using `.newdiv{display:none;}` either in your css file or inline code like: `<div style="display:none;">`

then use a callback function to only start after the code was inserted in the document when you used the after() method.

```
$('.myDiv').after('<div class="newdiv">added content</div>', function(){
    $('.newdiv').slideDown();
});
```